# Adding a CCSprite (NSObject) to a MutableArray crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsobject, ccsprite

I have a "bomb" `CCSprite` in its own class(If people who doesn't use cocos2d reads this, CCSprite is a NSObject pretty much).

The CCSprite file looks like this:

```
Bomb.h: 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <OpenAL/al.h>

@class HelloWorldLayer;

@interface Bomb : CCSprite {
    @private
    int length;


}
@property (readwrite) int length;

@end



Bomb.m:
#import "Bomb.h"


@implementation Bomb
@synthesize length = _length;

@end
```

I add it in my game layer (`HelloWorldLayer`like a pro) with `@class Bomb;` in .h, and I import the Bomb.h in my HWLayer.m aswell and where I use it in my code, is here:

```
Bomb *bombe = [[Bomb alloc] init];
bombe.position = explosionPoint;
bombe.length = player.explosionLength; //player is another CCSprite class. This one is from the method. ....fromPlayer:(PlayerSprite *)player
//Logging here works, tested and the bombe.position is valid and .length is valid 
[currentBombs addObject:bombe];
NSLog(@"%@",currentBombs); //Here doesn't, guessing crash is at ^
```

As said, it crashes on the `addObject:`line. I can't really see why, as I just replaced a not-classed CCSprite with a `Bomb`class. 
The crash is just a `(lldb)` and the thing on the left outputs a few thousand of these:

[image]

Which says description, so I would assume its in my CCSprite subclass the error is. BUT the bombe.* logging worked fine!

Does anyone understand why it doesn't work?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: That looks like "infinite" recursion in the description method of CCSprite. It might be possible to find the problem if you put the slider at the bottom of the Debug Navigator to the far right so that *all* frames are shown.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah! Look at the edited question, does it tell you anything else?

Comment: It certainly looks like an infinite recursion. Can you post the method: `-[CCSprite description]` and (if you've implemented it) `-[Bomb description]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
NSLog(@"%@",currentBombs); //Here doesn't, guessing crash is at ^
```

Your %@ implies `NSString`. currentBombs is likely an int. Try

```
NSLog(@"%i",currentBombs); //Here doesn't, guessing crash is at ^
```

`CCSprite` requires a texture. You can (maybe?) have a `CCSprite` without one, but that's not what `CCSprite` is for.

You will want to use `CCNode` for this purpose:

```
CCNode* node = [CCNode new];
```

This is a full-fledged Cocos2d object that you can move, etc. You'd add your Bomb to it, and move the CCNode around, like this:

```
Bomb *myBomb = [Bomb new]; //or whatever
CCNode* bombNode = [CCNode new];

//add the bomb to the node
[bombNode addChild:myBomb];

//move the node
bombNode.position = CGPointMake(10, 20)
```

This allows you to remove the `myBomb` from your node, effectively having something that you can add whatever you want without needing to display anything, but when you want to, it can be done easily.

Good luck

Comment: Currentbombs is a NSMurableArray ;) Edt: Subclassing it to CCNode makes it stop crashing. Will investigate if functionality is retained

Comment: -1 `Your %@ implies NSString. currentBombs is likely an int`: both wrong.

Comment: @Mar0ux Is there a better way to log arrays? I've always done it with %@

Comment: `%@` implies `id`/Objective-C object (not `NSString`). It is the right way to log arrays or any other Obj-C object.

Comment: @Mar0ux Ah, you were talking to him. I understand. and Blaine, this fixed it, I learned something new, everything is good!

Answer (score -1):

try this method :

```
Bomb *bombe = [Bomb spriteWithFile:@"yourFile.png"];
bombe.position = explosionPoint;
bombe.length = player.explosionLength;
[currentBombs addObject:bombe];
NSLog(@"%@",currentBombs);
```

Comment: I actually dont want it to have an image though - but I tried it anyway, and it still crashes.